# Org Babel can't execute script that takes table as input

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I want to learn [Org Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) so I'm going through [Code Blocks in Org](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#source-code-blocks-org).

I'm trying to execute the script in the basic tutorial and for some reason can't do it.

I'm supposed to feed a table as input to a function. This is the table:

```
#+name: tbl-example-data()
#+begin_src R 
runif(n=5, min=0, max=1)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: tbl-example-data
|  0.607781215803698 | 
|  0.157157169422135 |
|  0.675619817571715 |
| 0.0488600700628012 |
|  0.998780139256269 |
```

The next function is the function to be executed:

```
#+name: R-mean(x)
#+begin_src R 
mean(x)
#+end_src
```

When I try to run it by pressing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> I get

> Variable "x" in block "R-mean" must be assigned a default value.

I tried to explicitly run the `R-mean(x)` function like so:

```
#+call: R-mean(tbl-example-data)
```

Unfortunately I get:

> Reference 'R-mean' not found in this buffer.

How do I run the `R-mean` function using the values from `tbl-example-data`?

Thanks in advance.

Jenia

---

Okay I changed the code as per  instructions:

```
#+NAME: tbl-example-data()
#+BEGIN_SRC R :results value  <-------------------- changed
runif(n=5, min=0, max=1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: tbl-example-data
|  0.565871287835762 |
|  0.457158328965306 |
| 0.0498181856237352 |
|  0.988381117349491 |
|  0.898329895688221 |



#+NAME: R-mean(x)
#+BEGIN_SRC R :var x=tbl-example-data <-------------- changed
mean(x)
#+END_SRC




#+call: R-mean(x=tbl-example-data)
```

It returns me this:

```
 Reference 'R-mean' not found in this buffer.
```

I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make a couple of small changes in order to make this work.

1. Add `:results value` to the header of your first code block:

   ```
   #+NAME: tbl-example-data()
   #+BEGIN_SRC R :results value
   runif(n=5, min=0, max=1)
   #+END_SRC

   #+RESULTS: tbl-example-data
   ...
   ```
2. Add `:var x=tbl-example-data` to the header of your second code block:

   ```
   #+NAME: R-mean(x)
   #+BEGIN_SRC R :var x=tbl-example-data
   mean(x)
   #+END_SRC
   ```

With these changes in place, both ways you describe for obtaining the final result will work. Evaluating the second code block via <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> gives:

```
#+RESULTS: R-mean
: 0.49763968242332357
```

And calling the `R-mean` function via `#+CALL: R-mean(tbl-example-data)` produces:

```
#+RESULTS:
: 0.49763968242332357
```

#### Sources

- [Capturing the Results of Code Evaluation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#results)
- [Arguments to Code Blocks](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#arguments-to-source-code-blocks)

Comment: Hi itsjeyd. Thanks very much for your help. However, it didnt work for me for some reason. It tells me that "R-mean is not defined in this buffer". Maybe there's something else to do?

Comment: @JeniaIvanov Please describe exactly what you are doing when you are getting this error. Which block are you evaluating? Where is point (your cursor)? What keys are you pressing? I tried again with the modified version of your code and I can not reproduce the error. Also: What version of `org-mode` are you using? (Do `M-x org-version RET` to find out.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I wanted to add this in case it will be useful for others. itsjeyd's answer didn't fully work for me either, and I believe this is why.

There are three changes that need to be made.

1. As itsjeyd pointed out, you need a default value for `x` in your function `R-mean`. You can put `:var x=tbl-example-data`, but you could also just put `:var x=0`.
2. You need to remove change `#+NAME: R-mean(x)` to `#+NAME: R-mean`.
3. When you pass `x` it's being read as a one-column data frame, not a vector (for me at least). So you may need to change `mean(x)` to `mean(x[, 1])`.

For me, the first code block returns a table regardless of whether I use `:results value`. Your mileage may vary.

This works for me.

```
#+NAME: tbl-example-data()
#+BEGIN_SRC R
runif(n=5, min=0, max=1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: tbl-example-data
| 0.926858797203749 |
| 0.830021075671539 |
| 0.788423302117735 |
| 0.794694420881569 |
| 0.943031084956601 |


#+NAME: R-mean
#+BEGIN_SRC R :var x=""
mean(x[, 1])
#+END_SRC


#+call: R-mean(x=tbl-example-data)

#+RESULTS:
: 0.856605736166239
```

One final note. If you have parentheses at the end of your first block name, `#+NAME: tbl-example-data()`, this block appears not to be evaluate anew each time. So running the call statement multiple times produces the same result.

But if you remove the parentheses, giving `#+NAME: tbl-example-data`, the block is evaluate each time the call statement is run, producing a different result each time. I didn't know this.

Hope that helps!